# delete pointers and reallocation are giving same result in c++?

Tags: c++

I have problem with c++ pointer delete and re allocation. please give me a idea about this two method. I have no chance to use smart pointers.(This is not an actual code- I should replace reference type with int)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    queue<int*>q;

    int* a= new int(5);
    q.push(a);

   /* 1. method */
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int* x = q.pop();
        ....do something...
        delete x;/* is here deleting the firstly created int a object? */
       /* or only deleting newly created allocation of *x? */
    }

    /* 2. method */
    int* x = q.pop();
    while (!q.empty()) {        
        ....do something...
        *x = q.pop();

    }
    /* here i'm reallocating the values for x. is here deleting firstly created  int a object? */
    /* is 2 method = 1 method ? */


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::queue::pop()` doesn't return anything. Does this even compile?

Comment: Do you need pointers? `queue<int>` should be sufficient.

Comment: Ask an actual question please.

Comment: I want to know about pointers only. 
actual question is complex code. here is small to quick understand.
if you don't no about pointers please skip

Comment: The problem is not about whether we can answer, it's whether we can answer better than the countless references out there that _already_ explain in great detail how pointers and allocation works.

Comment: I dont see any reallocation taking place in that code and I dont see how your method1 is supposed to do the same as method2

Comment: is the 1 method is correct? then the first allocations of int a's are deleting?

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think you should ask a different question, namely about the decision that made you putting raw pointers in a container, which is rather questionable.

Comment: There is just one allocation in that program - `new int(5)`. Don't confuse the location of a thing with the thing itself.

Comment: are you saying that we do not do any deletion manually here?

Comment: I don't quite understand why it's so hard to understand how `new` and `delete` work.  When you call `new`, you are returned a *value*.  When you call `delete`, you must give it the same value.  All of this extraneous things you're doing with `queue` doesn't change this fact.  If you call `new`, stick that return value somewhere, and by whatever means, get that value back and call `delete`, then that's all you need to know.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie.  thanks. I got it

Answer (score 0):

> `delete x;/* is here deleting the firstly created int a object? */`

Yes.  The `new` call allocated memory and returned a pointer, which you pushed onto your queue.  You then (tried to) pop the value into `x`.  You can copy pointers around as much as you want, but they are only allocated and deleted *once*.

> `/* or only deleting newly created allocation of *x? */`

What?  No.  Whatever you were trying to ask, the answer is no.  The question is troubling.

> `/* here i'm reallocating the values for x. is here deleting firstly created  int a object? */`

No, you are not "reallocating the values for x".  Assuming this code compiles (which it doesn't), but assuming that it does what it's obvious you thought it should do, then the answer is no.  You also do not delete the "firstly created int a object".

What happens is you leak the memory for the original value stored in `a` (and subsequently pushed to your queue) because you never delete it.  Furthermore, the queue is empty after the first pop and you never enter the loop.

But if you *did* enter the loop, you have a type conflict where you are now storing the pointer you just popped into the integer-sized memory location you originally allocated in `a` and popped out into `x`.  Your compiler should warn you about this.

Now let's suppose you instead say (and here I'm also showing you the correct way to access and pop from `std::queue`):

```
x = q.front();
q.pop();
```

Now you have still leaked the old value of `x` because you did not store it anywhere else and did not delete it.  And you have replaced it with the next value in the queue, which you also don't delete and so you also presumably leak.

> `/* is 2 method = 1 method ? */`

No.  Method 1 is the most correct, but you still have it wrong.  You meant:

```
while( !q.empty() )
{
    int *x = q.front();
    q.pop();

    // do something...

    delete x;
}
```